# How to insert username password into sqlite on login If not exists?

Tags: angularjs, sqlite, ionic-framework

I want to insert a username and password into sqlite on login if not exists, because I want to keep registration and login db separately.

How can I check and insert?

Comment: Did you make a search? Did you have any attempt or code?

Comment: Look at below i tried this but i dont know how to use last_insert_rowid().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply update your table schema like following and push an insert query.

```
CREATE TABLE tblLogin (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, username VARCHAR, password VARCHAR, UNIQUE(username) ON CONFLICT IGNORE)
```

`ON CONFLICT IGNORE` will ignore the insert query if the username still exist in the table.

Just to make it clear, `last_insert_rowid()` will still return a valid id even if the insert query is ignored and database connection is same which invoked the function. Reference [here](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks For Your valuable Comments.And I have one more doubt.Its alerting insert id first time inserting.but if im insert same it will alert insert id as undefined

Comment: You might be closing the database after each interaction. It will only return `last_insert_rowid()` if the database connection is same which invoked the function.

Comment: $scope.insert = function(name,password) {
   alert(name);
        var query = "INSERT INTO customer_logindetails (customerName,password) VALUES (?,?)";
        $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, [name,password]).then(function(res) {
            alert("INSERT ID -> " + res.insertId);
            SELECT last_insert_rowid();
        }, function (err) {
            alert(err);
        });
    }
Is this is Right?????????I think im Getting error

Answer (score 1):

ngCordova Supports a plugin called "$cordovaSQLite". Go through [this](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/sqlite/) its actually very simple.

Once Installed use this tutorial [Blog](https://blog.nraboy.com/2014/11/use-sqlite-instead-local-storage-ionic-framework/)